# Problem with Writing files using FileWriter automatically with Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, filewriter

I have chosen nearly 200 files to write on a position automatically on a particular time. Created a separate job names in Quartz scheduler. The job will be triggered on a time. I can read the files only after all the files have been written. I could not read after one file is written. I have closed the FileWriter after one file written. What is the solution to access the file and read which have been written into the hard Disk

```java
File f = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + context.getTrigger()
        .getJobName() + ".sql");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
System.out.println("DBname is " + scheduleInfo.get("dbName"));
fw.append("CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `" + scheduleInfo.get("dbName") + "` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;\nUSE `"
        + scheduleInfo.get("dbName") + "`;\n");
ps1 = con.prepareStatement(dbname_exist);
ps1.setString(1, (String) scheduleInfo.get("dbName"));
rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
if (rs1.next()) {
    backup_exits = true;

}

// if (br.readLine() == null||!backup_exits)
if (br.readLine() == null) {
    ps = con.prepareStatement(backup_data);
    ps.setString(1, (String) scheduleInfo.get("sch_id"));
    ps.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Failed to download file");
} else {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        fw.append(line + "\n");
    }
}

br.close();
fw.close();
```

Comment: Please post some illustrative code.  Particularly, the code that attempts to read the files, and the code (or whatever) that causes that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure file outputstream is closed properly. Further close the file object instance as well

Comment: *"close the file object instance as well"*  how?

Comment: I am sorry... I mean make sure you are not holding the reference to the file object. I am not sure if that causes an issue but I did experience issues with reading of the file unless I got rid of all references to the file object used for writing